# CloudFront - disable access to distribution via d1234.cloudfront.net

Tags: google-search, googlebot, amazon-cloudfront

I have a CloudFront distribution with a configured alternative name (e.g. `cdn.example.com`). Is it possible to restrict access to the CDN via `d1234.cloudfront.net` name?

I don't want it to be indexed if we place a link to `d1234.cloudfront.net` by mistake.

Comment: Are you able to use canonical tags to fix this?

Comment: @jrtapsell We use cannonical tags. However, they do not prevent Google from indexing that other domain and showing it in search results. We already had that problem.

Comment: So for `d1234.cloudfront.net` you are serving a canonical URL on `cdn.example.com`?

Comment: @jrtapsell Exactly. Yet, Google indexes both domains and shows them both in the search results. Probably, lower our rankings in the process since it sees duplicated content.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is uploading a separate robots.txt file for CloudFront URL. This will not block the CloudFront URL but will keep it away from google search

Create robots_cf.txt file that contains this text:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Now add this rule to `.htaccess` file (say Cloudfront URL is `aaabbbcccddd.cloudfront.net`):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^aaabbbcccddd.*$ [NC]    
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*robots\.txt.*\ HTTP/ [NC]    
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt /robots_cf.txt [NC,L]
```

Eventually, Google will get this and stop crawling your CloudFront URL.